# Can't solve 'SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"' issue

Tags: java, slf4j

I am trying to use a biological program and I have this output error when I run it:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I have seen all the threads that are leading with this issue, trying all different binding files with no result. Here is what I have in my bashrc file:

```
# Set CLASSPATH
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/class/slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar
```

I have seen that the program uses the 'slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar' (that's why I used the same binding versions) and I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Any idea?

Thank you!

Comment: How did that jar file end up there?  If you put it there, you are doing things wrong.  Also "java -jar" ignores $CLASSPATH

Comment: This usually happens when either no logger is found or multiple loggers are are found in classpath. Look into the dependency structure of your project and trace what all logger implementations are available. You might have to explicitly exclude it for some entries in pom.xml.

Comment: @techtrainer the message for multiple loggers is different.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I found 'slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar' inside the program, that's why I put the simple.jar in my classpath. The readme of the program tells that you have to start it with 'java -jar...'

Comment: @JaimeG if you use "java -jar" it means that the normal classpath mechanism is disabled and only classpath entries in the manifests are used.  You may have to manually construct an equivalent classpath and add slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar to that or adjust manifests by hand.   This is not necessarily easy.    But the SLF4J messages are not fatal, they just mean that the program will not log.  It will still run though.  Do you need it for anything?

Comment: Thanks for your help @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen!

Answer (score 0):

I was looking the answer from @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and I had to find the selected classpath inside the files of the program, add the "slf4j-simple-1.6.6.jar" binding to the code and paste it to the path. Finally the error has gone.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: In that case this question is most likely a duplicate of a "how do I change the classpath of an executable jar".  Future reviewers might fix that :)